# How to get rid of Projects added to this solution error after cloaking folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-explorer, source-control-explorer

My team has a solution containing several projects.  We use Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio 2013 for source control.  I never deal with the two setup projects in the solution, so I thought cloaking those folders (In Source Control) would be great so I don't have to see them and deal with them.  But when I cloak those two folders, every time I open the solution I get a message box telling me "Projects have recently been added to this solution.  Do you want to get them from source control?"  No matter whether I choose yes or no, I continue to get this message box every time I open the solution.  If I uncloak the folders, I no longer get this message box.  Also, even after cloaking, the projects still show up in my Solution Explorer. Has anyone had this issue, or know how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Tried removing the projects from the solution?

Comment: I don't want to remove the projects from the solution, because I still need them in TFS so my developers can access them and generate the setup files.  I don't need them, but the other developers in my team do.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to comment but don't have enough points. Just create another solution without the setup projects.

This way you will have two solutions in TFS, one with the setup projects and one without.

Comment: I can't do that, because when it syncs with TFS, all my other developers will lose it too.

Comment: Not if you create a separate solution as described in the answer